# How to estimate many GLM models in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a dataset of 5000 variables. One target and 4999 covariates. I want to estimate one glm per each target-variable combination (4999 models).

How can I do that without manually typing 4999 formulas for GLM ?

In R I would simply define a list of 4999 strings ("target ~ x1) , convert each string to a formula and use map to estimate multiple glm. Is there something similar that can be done in Julia ? Or is there an elegant alternative ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can programatically create the formula via `Term` objects. The docs for that can be found [here](https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/latest/formula/#Constructing-a-formula-programmatically-1), but consider the following simple example which should meet your needs:

Start with dummy data

```
julia> using DataFrames, GLM

julia> df = hcat(DataFrame(y = rand(10)), DataFrame(rand(10, 5)))
10×6 DataFrame
│ Row │ y         │ x1        │ x2       │ x3        │ x4         │ x5       │
│     │ Float64   │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64   │ Float64    │ Float64  │
├─────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.0200963 │ 0.924856  │ 0.947904 │ 0.429068  │ 0.00833488 │ 0.547378 │
│ 2   │ 0.169498  │ 0.0915296 │ 0.375369 │ 0.0341015 │ 0.390461   │ 0.835634 │
│ 3   │ 0.900145  │ 0.502495  │ 0.38106  │ 0.47253   │ 0.637731   │ 0.814095 │
│ 4   │ 0.255163  │ 0.865253  │ 0.791909 │ 0.0833828 │ 0.741899   │ 0.961041 │
│ 5   │ 0.651996  │ 0.29538   │ 0.161443 │ 0.23427   │ 0.23132    │ 0.947486 │
│ 6   │ 0.305908  │ 0.170662  │ 0.569827 │ 0.178898  │ 0.314841   │ 0.237354 │
│ 7   │ 0.308431  │ 0.835606  │ 0.114943 │ 0.19743   │ 0.344216   │ 0.97108  │
│ 8   │ 0.344968  │ 0.452961  │ 0.595219 │ 0.313425  │ 0.102282   │ 0.456764 │
│ 9   │ 0.126244  │ 0.593456  │ 0.818383 │ 0.485622  │ 0.151394   │ 0.043125 │
│ 10  │ 0.60174   │ 0.8977    │ 0.643095 │ 0.0865611 │ 0.482014   │ 0.858999 │
```

Now when you run a linear model with GLM, you'd do something like `lm(@formula(y ~ x1), df)`, which indeed can't easily be used in a loop to construct different formulas. We'll therefore follow the docs and create the output of the `@formula` macro directly - remember macros in Julia just transform syntax to other syntax, so they don't do anything we can't write ourselves!

```
julia> lm(Term(:y) ~ Term(:x1), df)
StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

y ~ 1 + x1

Coefficients:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                 Coef.  Std. Error      t  Pr(>|t|)   Lower 95%  Upper 95%
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)   0.428436    0.193671   2.21    0.0579  -0.0181696   0.875041
x1           -0.106603    0.304597  -0.35    0.7354  -0.809005    0.595799
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

You can verify for yourself that the above is equivalent to `lm(@formula(y ~ x1), df)`.

Now it's hopefully an easy step to building the loop that you're looking for (restricted to two covariates below to limit the output):

```
julia> for x ∈ names(df[:, Not(:y)])[1:2]
           @show lm(term(:y) ~ term(x), df)
       end
lm(term(:y) ~ term(x), df) = StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

y ~ 1 + x1

Coefficients:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                 Coef.  Std. Error      t  Pr(>|t|)   Lower 95%  Upper 95%
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)   0.428436    0.193671   2.21    0.0579  -0.0181696   0.875041
x1           -0.106603    0.304597  -0.35    0.7354  -0.809005    0.595799
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
lm(Term(:y) ~ Term(x), df) = StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

y ~ 1 + x2

Coefficients:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                 Coef.  Std. Error      t  Pr(>|t|)  Lower 95%  Upper 95%
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)   0.639633    0.176542   3.62    0.0068   0.232527    1.04674
x2           -0.502327    0.293693  -1.71    0.1256  -1.17958     0.17493
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

As Dave points out below, it's helpful to use the `term()` function here to create our terms rather than the `Term()` constructor directly - this is because `names(df)` returns a vector of `String`s, while the `Term()` constructor expects `Symbol`s. `term()` has a method for `String`s that handles the conversion automatically.

Comment: Not necessarily relevant here but you can use the "lowercase" `term` function instead of the `Term` constructor directly if your terms include a `1` for the intercept.  It also passes through any `AbstractTerm` unchanged.  https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsModels.jl/blob/master/src/terms.jl#L579-L599

Comment: Inspired by this question I created a pull request which should be merged soon (https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/pull/20638 that mean) so from v0.6.14 of StatsModels you can do `terms(names(df))` directly and `terms` will convert the strings to symbols for you

Comment: may be worth editing your answer to reflect that?  0.6.14 is released now

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the low-level API and pass the dependent variable as a vector and the independent variable as a matrix directly without even building formulas. You will lose coefficient names, but since you have only one independent variable in each model it's probably OK.

This is documented in [`?fit`](https://juliastats.org/GLM.jl/dev/api/#StatsBase.fit). The call for each model will look like `glm([ones(length(x1)) x1], target, dist)`. The column full of ones is for the intercept.