# Julia: Iterating over columns in a dataframe and calculate LinearRegression

Tags: plot, julia, linear-regression

I have a data frame with 10 columns(features) COL0 to COL9 and a column RESP. How do I calculate a LinearRegression Model for each pair COL0 to COL9 ~ RESP?
I am expecting to get 10 graphs showing the Model and also a table with the coefficients of my model for each column.

What I tried do far:

```
model2 = fit(LinearModel, @formula(RESP ~EXPL_0 + EXPL_1 + EXPL_2 + 
EXPL_3 + EXPL_4 +  EXPL_5 + EXPL_6 + EXPL_7 + EXPL_8 + EXPL_9), df)
```

And I get what i want.

I still need to know how to plot all this graphs
and if I had `COL0 to COL1000`, how do I can avoid to type all the columns from 0 to 1000?

I am new to Julia and I really dont have a clue how to get this done. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Consider adding a minimal working example. I'm not sure everyone knows that @formula comes from StatsModels.jl or is willing to look that up. Also it's not clear to me what you want to do. Plot some kind of graphs...? Why do you suddenly have 1000 columns from the initial 10?

Comment: I said 10 columns to make it easier to explain.  I can have dataframes with N-columns + the Predicted one.  I want to plot the graphs and whats important to me is to know which columns impact the most my model, i mean which data columns show the the higher or lower Coeff.  How can I extract the top 3 that impact the most my model?  maybe a heatmap like in pyton..i am really new to Julia.

Comment: So, my questions are: How to optimeze the formula to consider a range of columns?  How can I plot each pair Column + PRED automatically? How can I extract the top3 columns that has the data that impact the most my mode?

Comment: You ask many questions and some of them are broad. I would start with the first question - how to programatically select columns for the model. To do this check out this tutorial https://github.com/JuliaAcademy/DataFrames/blob/main/2.%20First%20steps%20with%20data%20frames.ipynb that shows you how to construct formulas programmatically on an example. Also here is a link to documentation that explains it: https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/stable/formula/#Constructing-a-formula-programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As Bogumil says, it's not ideal to ask many questions in one post on StackOverflow - your question should be well defined and targeted, ideally with a minimum working example to make it easiest for people to help you.

Let's therefore answer what from the title of the post I take as your main question: how can I fit a linear regression model with `GLM` which includes many response columns. That question is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629886/how-to-estimate-many-glm-models-in-julia/63630435#63630435), so a very similar answer applies: broadcast the `term` function over the `names` in your DataFrame which you want to include on the right hand side like this:

```
julia> using DataFrames, GLM

julia> df = hcat(DataFrame(RESP = rand(100)), DataFrame(rand(100, 10), :auto));

julia> mymodel = lm(term(:RESP) ~ sum(term.(names(df[!, Not(:RESP)]))), df)
StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Vector{Float64}}, GLM.DensePredChol{Float64, LinearAlgebra.CholeskyPivoted{Float64, Matrix{Float64}}}}, Matrix{Float64}}

RESP ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10
(...)
```

You also ask about plotting, but that's probably best dealt with in a separate question. You can access the estimated coefficients of your linear model using the `coef` function, e.g.

```
julia> coef(mymodel)
11-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.504236533528822
  0.11712812154185266
 -0.0206810430546413
 -0.15693089456050294
 -0.011916514466331067
 -0.1030171434361648
  0.10378957999147352
 -0.09447743618381275
 -0.08860977078650123
  0.0816071818033377
  0.09939548661830626
```

and the full output with `coeftable`.

Finally note that you won't necessarily see from that which columns "impact most" your model as you say in the comment, unless you have standardized your regressors.